How to prevent toggling an accordion in bootstrap when the user clicks on specific part of a button thats used to toggle an accordion
I am using bootstrap.
Here, you can see this is a standard accordion. However, I want non-standard behaviour from it.
When a user clicks on elements with the class 'option', it selects the 'suboptions' like it should. But then it also expands the accordion-item.
This is an annoying behaviour in my opinion.
index.html:
<ul class="accordion" id="collection-accordion">
  <li class="accordion-item text-center py-3"><h4 class="accordion-header">Collection</h4></li>
  
  <li class="accordion-item">
    <h3 class="accordion-header d-flex align-items-center">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed h4 flex-grow-1" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#filterCol-1" aria-controls="filterCol-1">
        <label class="fs-6 me-2 mb-0">
          <input type="checkbox" class="option">
          Deep Groove Bearings
        </label>
        <span class="product-count fw-normal mx-2">&#40;560&#41;</span>
      </button>
    </h3>
    <ul class="accordion-collapse collapse" id="filterCol-1" data-bs-parent="#collection-accordion">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <li><label><input type="checkbox" class="subOption">6000 Series<span class="product-count">&#40;450&#41;</span></label></li>
        <li><label><input type="checkbox" class="subOption">6200 Series<span class="product-count">&#40;32&#41;</span></label></li>
        <li><label><input type="checkbox" class="subOption">6300 Series<span class="product-count">&#40;69&#41;</span></label></li>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </li>

</ul>

index.js:
document.querySelectorAll('input.option').forEach(option => {
  const subOptions = option.closest('li').querySelectorAll('input.subOption');

  option.onclick = function() {
    subOptions.forEach(subOption => {
      subOption.checked = this.checked;
    });
  }

  subOptions.forEach(subOption => {
    subOption.onclick = function() {
      const checkedCount = option.closest('li').querySelectorAll('input.subOption:checked').length;

      option.checked = checkedCount > 0;
      option.indeterminate = checkedCount > 0 && checkedCount < subOptions.length;
    }
  });
});

How do I achieve behaviour so that when user clicks on the option:
<label class="fs-6 me-2 mb-0">
  <input type="checkbox" class="option">
  Deep Groove Bearings
</label>

the suboptions get selected, but the accordion stays in its original state: either collapsed or expanded.
I have tried moving it out of the button itself, but then I cant get the desired look.
I have also tried asking various AIs through various ways, including using .stopPropagation(), .preventDefault(), .stopImmediatePropagation, but was unsuccessful.
Maybe these methods were applied on the wrong elements.
The objective is to not compromise the styling.
Any thoughts on how to accomplish this without a lot of code added?

I apologize if I didn't give enough details, this is my first time writing a question. Thanks!

Your HTML is invalid in several respects (eg div as a direct child of a ul and input element within a button). Please correct these problems first. You may find using a code validator is helpful e.g. https://validator.w3.org/

Respectfully, correcting my html wouldnt solve the issue at hand. Yes, I am aware that div cannot be a direct child of a ul. nor that you can have input within a button.
But the purpose of the button here is to toggle an accordion, it can also be a div according to how bootstrap works. Regardless, is there not other ways than to take input  outside of the element toggling the accordion?

I wasn't trying to correct your problem, I would have made an answer if correcting your syntax would correct it, that's why I made a comment instead,  You do need to correct the syntax first as browser behavior might be unpredictable (browsers tend to 'do their best' to run whatever code they find, but not always consistently).

Ohk I see why that's a problem, thanks for your help!

The easiest way is to take the input out of the button trigger.
<h3 class="accordion-header d-flex align-items-center">
  <input type="checkbox" class="option" />
  <button
    class="accordion-button collapsed h4 flex-grow-1"
    type="button"
    data-bs-toggle="collapse"
    data-bs-target="#filterCol-1"
    aria-controls="filterCol-1"
  >
    <label class="fs-6 me-2 mb-0"> Deep Groove Bearings </label>
    <span class="product-count fw-normal mx-2">&#40;560&#41;</span>
  </button>
</h3>

But if the input has to be in the button for any reason, you'll have to

input cannot be within a button.

I will try and take input out and do it through position: absolute;
